# Spring boot BigQuery datasource connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am trying to connect BigQuery from Spring boot using Simba jdbc driver but I am getting below exception. Any input is appreciated. I am not sure why spring-boot is looking for a certifcate. I am able to connect with simple java main class, But I am getting this error with Spring boot only.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [com/test/demo/services/config/DBConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver HttpTransport IO error : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

```
DataSource ds = new com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.DataSource();
Connection connection = null;
ds.setURL(
    "jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=project)id;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=serviceAccountEmail;OAuthPvtKeyPath=p12CertPath;");

ds.setProjectId("projectId");
// ds.setOAuthType(0);

// connection = ds.getConnection();
connection = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: From the documentation: "The following is the format of the connection: `jdbc:bigquery://[Host]:[Port];ProjectId=[Project];OAuthType=[AuthValue];[Property1]=[Value1];[Property2]=[Value2];...`". Your URL doesn't look like that. Also, try removing the spaces after then `;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra spaces from your JDBC URL, it looks like they are interfering with mandatory `OAuthPvtKeyPath`, `OAuthServiceAcctEmail` parameters:

```
jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;ProjectId=<Your Project ID>;OAuthType=0;OAuthServiceAcctEmail=<Your Email>;OAuthPvtKeyPath=<Path To Cert>;
```

Comment: After removing spaces I am getting this error now. Spring is looking for certificate path. But we are not using certs other than p12 file
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name dataSource.[com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100004) HttpTransport IO error : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.